# Android Invalid Zip archive error in libs while trying to import older version of project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a rather large application and encountered some problems with a newer version.  I then decided to restore to a version I saved the previous day.  After importing the project, I get an error for 7 of the files in the libs folder.  Below is one of them.  I have tried deleting the jar files and then putting them back in the folder.  However, no luck.  I can delete the jar files from the project, restart Eclipse, and I still get these errors.  It is apparently hardwired in the project somewhere.  How do I clean up my project so that I can reinstall these jar files or fix this problem?  Thanks.

Invalid ZIP archive: /Users/Mark/Documents/testworkspace/RaceDay/libs/._kinvey-android-lib-2.6.12.jar

Comment: I was importing code that was stored on a file encrypted with TrueCrypt.  Everything copied in fine except for these libs for some reason.  When I put the actual files out of the encrypted file, they imported fine.  So, problem is solved